# Perl read from infinite loop application

Tags: perl

InfLoop is a application that prints random number in infinite loop. The following statement is blocking, that is perl waits untill the application InfLoop exits.

```
$out=`./InfLoop`;
```

I would like to know is there any way to read the printed numbers in perl without waiting for InfLoop to exit. At least by using fork, IPC or any thing like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read arbitrary number of lines before closing pipe to `./InfLoop`

```
open my $pipe, "-|", "./InfLoop" or die $!;
# read first N lines
for my $i (1..3) {
  my $line = readline($pipe);
  print $line;
}
close($pipe);
```

Comment: How to make it bidirectional?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process